# How to subscribe to events properly in Windows Runtime apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I subscribe to `OrientationChanged` event in the constructor like this:

```
public SecondPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    deviceOrientationSensor = SimpleOrientationSensor.GetDefault();

    if (deviceOrientationSensor != null)
    {
        deviceOrientationSensor.OrientationChanged += OrientationChanged;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
private void OrientationChanged(SimpleOrientationSensor sender, SimpleOrientationSensorOrientationChangedEventArgs args)
{
    deviceOrientation = args.Orientation;
    // the rest...
}
```

So the problem is that when I navigate back to another page or go to the phone start screen, the next time it handles `OrientationChanged` event twice, and again for 3 times and so on.

it seems it subscribes to the event again without removing previous subscription. It happens not only for orientation change event, but for any other event too.

I thought I can unsubscribe on `OnNavigatedFrom` method, but it seems it is not guaranteed to happen unlike previous Windows Phone Silverlight apps.

How to prevent multiple subscriptions? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't subscribe in the pages, but in App.Xaml.cs instead.

2) Unsubscribe in the OnNavigatedFrom method:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  deviceOrientationSensor.OrientationChanged -= OrientationChanged;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. But this is specific to only this page and also, if I unsubscribe in `OnNavigatedFrom` method of the page, where the next time subscription occurs?

Comment: The subscription is being generated in the constructor for the page, so every time you go back to the page, it regenerates the subscription.  That's the cause of the problem to begin with.

Comment: I personally like to subscribe/unsubscribe in `OnNavigatedTo`, as both methods are generally right next to each other, so it's easy to see if I've forgotten. Is there anything inherently bad about subscribing in `OnNavigatedTo`?

Comment: Nate- you're absolutely right. The two bullets were meant as two options  for the resolution of this particular issue. Subscribe in OnNavigatedTo, unsubscribe in OnNavigatedFrom is an excellent pattern to use.