# Page state in Windows Runtime

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone

My problem is that I want to know when the user navigated to the page and when navigated away. So I can perform some page specific tasks like [subscribing and unsubscribing to events.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285471/how-to-subscribe-to-events-properly-in-windows-runtime-apps)

Previously it was obvious and we could override `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatingFrom` methods. But in Windows Phone Runtime, there is no guarantee those methods occur when the user switches between apps for example.

In Windows Phone Runtime, how to know when the user is opening a page and when going away (to another page, start screen or another app)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you navigate to another page - it's simple, you handle `NavigatingFrom`/`NavigatedTo`. When not - it's also simple - you shouldn't be getting these events and so you should do nothing in most cases. I've seen `NavigatingFrom` being raised though in certain circumstances when the app was getting suspended and navigation state was being read from the `Frame` even though technically in-app navigation wasn't occurring and there would be no matching `NavigatedTo` event on resume. You might want to filter that out by setting and clearing some flag in the `Suspending` event (or `Application.OnSuspending` override) before and after `NavigatingFrom` is triggered and then ignoring it in the page `NavigatingFrom` handler for certain code. You would probably still want to save the page state in that event, but not unsubscribe from other events in case the app gets resumed before it gets terminated.

`Application.Suspending/Resuming` are some events you might also be interested in for saving/loading overall app state or refreshing data, though maybe less so for subscribing/unsubscribing from events since most of these should be fine to leave alone when the app gets suspended which happens when you switch to another app.

`Page.Loaded/Unloaded` events are ones you would handle if you want to touch parts of the UI that need to actually be loaded in the visual tree, since `NavigatedTo` happens before the page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks Filip for the details